# Regular Expression how to add " to beginning and end of word

Tags: regex, expression

I have a json string that looks something like this:

```
    {
  operations: [
    validateAddressAndBRClassification, vintageValidateAddressAndGeo, deleteShareInformation, validateCountry, validatePostcode, pageThroughAddress, getFromRelationships, getToRelationships, getUnresolvedAddresses, validateCity, getVisits, getOperationalAddress, getGeo, looseAddressSearch, getServiceInformation, getAddress, getInternalProp, validateAddress, disputeBR, validateAddressAndGeo, supportedCountries, internalMx, getBRProfileHistory, databaseStatus, getBRProfile, addressLookup, getDataSourceMetaInformation, getBRDisputeHistory, validateStateProv, getGeopoliticalElementList, validatePostal, postalLookup, signalDataSourceChange, setInternalProp, getShareInformation, addVisit, addressSearch, getRelatedAddresses, ping, showOperations
  ]
}
```

I need to add a double quote " to the beginning and end of each word. What would the regular expression for this be?

So I need it to look like this:

```
{
  "operations": [
    "validateAddressAndBRClassification", "vintageValidateAddressAndGeo", "deleteShareInformation", "etc"
}
```

Comment: word boundaries are \b (\< and \> with grep). Afterwards it all depends on your definition of "word". I guess it would be something like "\b[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\b"

Comment: That matches my words but how do I add the " to the beginning and the end of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which programming language you are using but in JavaScript you could achieve it with the following line:

`string = string.replace(/(\w+)/g, "\"$1\"");`

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wLyL0hvk/

Comment: I am using the CA API Gateway's regular expression assertion to do this so I am not doing it with a language. However, the Gateway is written in Java so I'm assuming it uses some java library for regular expressions.

Comment: I don't know the CA API Gateway but after reading [this page](https://docops.ca.com/ca-api-gateway/8-3/en/policy-assertions/assertion-palette/message-validation-transformation-assertions/evaluate-regular-expression-assertion), I guess you have to check a "Match and Replace" option somewhere and use the following replacement string: "$1"

Comment: You are totally right. The answer is the regular expression should be \b[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\b and the replacement field is "$0"